# Why is state not changing when I call setFormData() from a certain place in my React code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the useState hook like this:

```
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    company: "",
    title: "",
    location: "",
    from: "",
    to: "",
    current: false,
    description: "",
  });
```

And I have two inputs that look like this:

```
 <div className="form-group">
          <p>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="current"
              checked={current}
              value={current}
              // use this to toggle the checkbox
              onChange={(e) => {
                if (!current) {
                  console.log("change");
                  setFormData({
                    ...formData,
                    to: null,
                    company: "test company",
                  });
                }
                setFormData({ ...formData, current: !current });
                toggleDisabled(!toDateDisabled);
                console.log({ formData });
              }}
            />{" "}
            Current Job
          </p>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <h4>To Date</h4>
          <input
            type="date"
            name="to"
            value={to}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
            disabled={current ? "disabled" : ""}
          />
        </div>
```

But if you look at my first input group, this part of the code is not doing anything at all:

```
if (!current) {
                  console.log("change");
                  setFormData({
                    ...formData,
                    to: null,
                    company: "test company",
                  });
                }
```

So, `current` is correctly changing, as I click the checkbox, the value of 'current`is toggling between true and false as it should. BUT, when it hits my if statement of`if(!current)` and I call setFormData, absolutely nothing happens. But if I were to add 'company: "test company" ' to the setFormData function directly below that one, the state is changing as it should.

So what is really going on here? How is my setFormData function only working outside of the if statement?

Comment: How is redux involved?

Comment: Oh good point, I guess the issue has nothing to do with redux and more with react?

Comment: And define “nothing happens”: you call setState again immediately after the “if” block; the state won’t have been updated yet. setState is async.

Comment: Well, you’re not using Redux in any of this code, so... yes, more to do with React. Everything, in fact.

Comment: I mean if I console .log the state, nothing changes within it, but changes do occur in the second setFormData. So you're saying I can't call setFormData one after another?

Comment: Sure, you *can*, but it seems like you’re ignoring that it’s async.

Comment: Basically my end goal is to change one of the values in the state to empty if the checkbox is selected

Comment: A reference for help understanding [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), also [State Updates are Merged](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onChange handler of your checkbox, you should be checking the new value of the checkbox rather than the `current` property in the state.
And you don't really need a value defined in the checkbox since you aren't using it for anything.
In a comment you said "Basically my end goal is to change one of the values in the state to empty if the checkbox is selected".
It looks like you want to change the `to` property to null and the company to blank when the user unchecks the checkbox.

Here's how you can accomplish specifically that.

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  name="current"
  checked={current}
  onChange={(e) => {
    // If the checkbox is now checked, preserve formData.to and formData.company.
    // Otherwise, overwrite to with null and company with "test company".

    setFormData({
        ...formData,
        to: e.target.checked ? formData.to : null,
        company: e.target.checked ? formData.company : "test company",
        current: e.target.checked,
    });
  }}
/>
```

### Full Test Component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const CheckboxTester = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    to: "",
    company: "",
    current: false,
  });

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="current"
        checked={formData.current}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFormData({
            ...formData,
            to: e.target.checked ? formData.to : null,
            company: e.target.checked ? formData.company : "test company",
            current: e.target.checked,
          });
        }}
      />
      <hr />
      <label>Current State</label>
      <br />
      <pre>
        {JSON.stringify(formData)}
      </pre>
    </>
  );
}

export default CheckboxTester;
```

Comment: I just tried it, but now the checkbox is not clicking.

Comment: Ah, sorry. My mistake. I was setting current to `!e.target.checked` in the setFormData handler. You need to set it to the new value of `e.target.checked` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `onchange` function is not working correctly. You see the toggle change in UI when you click but you don't set it in the state.

Could you try to handle input change the following way?

1. HTML for input

```html
<p>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      name="current"
      checked={formData.checked}
      onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e)}
    /> 
    Current Job
</p>
```

2. Input change handler for html

```js
function handleInputChange(e) {
  const { current } = formData;
  const { checked } = e.target;

  // only if current is false
  if (!current) {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      checked,
      current: !current,
    });
  }
}
```